# Receiving null to Post method when request content is over a certain size

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

First of all the request content size triggering this is 632 bytes so I don't believe its related to maxRequestLength parameter. I've tried increasing this and it hasn't helped. The request content is available via ReadAsStreamAsync so its not IIS blocking it.

I have a controller with a Post method which takes a class object. This always works from my development machine and most of the time it works on our QA server under IIS. It looks like -

```
[RoutePrefix("api/message")]
public class MessageController : ApiController
{
    [Route("send")
    public async Task<SendMessageResponse> PostSend([FromBody] SendMessageRequest request)
    {
        ...
```

SendMessageRequest looks like -

```
public class SendMessageRequest
{
    public string[] sendTo { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
}
```

However when the request content is over 632 characters PostSend receives null as the request parameter. It is possible to manually pull the request stream and serialise using Newtonsoft.JSON.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Hector

*Example request content

```
{
    "subject" : "Test Message",
    "sendTo" : [ "hector@employer.com" ],
    "body" : "...Long String..."
}
```

Changing subject or body to bring the request content over 632 bytes will cause null to be passed to PostSend

Comment: Can you post sample code for how you are calling the API method?

Comment: If you say that it works on your env and on QA as well, it might be the case of misconfiguration. I'd use Fiddler to track the raw request and response and see if that yields anything

Comment: @JuanR - added an example request content. Deserialisation is handled by ASP.NET. I can reproduce by sending identical messages and increasing the subject or body to take it over the character limit.

Comment: @AndreiU - Its the same Web.Config for both. It only fails under IIS so I can't run fiddler but I have logged full request content and for otherwise identical requests with a few extra characters added to the body or subject I can reliably get it to fail.

Comment: Can you post the code that actually calls the API? Are you using JS and JQuery?

Comment: @JuanR - In QA its being called from a JS based client application however i'm logging the full request body so know this is correct and that the extra character isn't causing it to be malformed. The headers could potentially be large but increasing the maxRequestLength setting to 10MB made no difference so I don't believe its related to this.

Comment: Have you checked the request limits? (not the same as maxRequestLength): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/index

Comment: @JuanR - If it were IIS limits surely it would never make it through to my call? And I wouldn't be able to manually read the request body?

Comment: You are making assumptions and that may very well be the reason you can't figure this out. The problem usually lies in the places we **don't** look in. Even if it seems like it shouldn't be the cause, take a look. It can't hurt.

Comment: And please do post sample payload as well as the code that calls the API in the environment where it does **not** work.

Comment: @JuanR - I've posted example payload already. I've investigated the IIS limits already before posting - increasing them does not help. I can't post a full request including headers because there is private information in several of the headers.

Comment: I see. Good luck figuring it out.

Comment: @JuanR -Thanks :) Turns out WebApi doesn't play well with chunked requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out in production and QA we have a node based server which proxies requests. This passes the request on in Chunked form.

There appears to be a bug in WebApi v2.1 with chunked request handling as per https://forums.asp.net/t/1978292.aspx.

The solution is to add something into the pipeline before the deserializer which sets request.Content.Headers.ContentLength = null.

i.e.

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (request.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked.HasValue 
        && request.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked.Value)
    {
        request.Content.Headers.ContentLength = null;
    }
    return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
```